# Azure Function Error: "Your function app does not support remote build..."

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I try to deploy an Azure Function to the cloud using... `func azure functionapp publish appName --build remote --publish-local-settings`

...I receive the following error

```
Getting site publishing info...
Remote build is a new feature added to function apps.
Your function app appName does not support remote build as it was created before August 1st, 2019.
Please use '--build local' or '--build-native-deps'.
For more information, please visit https://aka.ms/remotebuild
```

EVEN THOUGH THE APP WAS LITERALLY JUST CREATED IN AZURE PORTAL.

**System:**
- Running VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Create a new Function App (and support resources) using `az cli`

  - Python runtime
  - Consumption plan
  - StandardV2 Storage plan
  - AppInsights
- Create new Function (scaffolding) using VS Code Azure Functions extension
- Create `__init__.py` and configure `local.settings.json`
- Open a terminal; `cd` to Function folder
- Run `func azure functionapp publish appName --build remote --publish-local-settings`
- Fails everytime with the message above

**Tried so far:**
- Substituting `--build local`. 
  - Looks like it wants to work, but fails with error

```
There was an error restoring dependencies. ERROR: cannot install cryptography-2.9.2 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported when building locally. Use the "--build remote" option to build dependencies on the Azure Functions build server, or "--build-native-deps" option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish
```

**Not going to try:**
- `--build-local-deps` because I don't want a docker instance for my Function App

Please advise. This is painful at this point.

Comment: Just to make sure, which `appName` did you use when you run the command `func azure functionapp publish appName --build remote` ? Local function app name or the name of the function app you created on azure portal ?

Comment: The name of the Function App created in Portal (not local name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was found today:

- I initially created the Function App Storage Account with...

```
# Create a Function App Storage Account

az storage account create \
    --name $fa_storage_name \
    --resource-group $rg_name \
    --access-tier Cool \
    --default-action Deny \
    --kind StorageV2 \
    --subscription $az_sub
    --location $az_loc \
    --sku Standard_LRS
```

Changed this to...

```
# Create a Function App Storage Account

az storage account create \
    --name $fa_storage_name \
    --resource-group $rg_name \
    --location $az_loc \
    --sku Standard_LRS
```

...and was able to get past that error. The way I stumbled onto this was using the `--buld local` flag. It gave me a MUCH MORE ACCURATE error. Something along the lines of `Check your storage account dude.`

(thank you Marcelo!)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was provisioning an [`azurerm_linux_function_app`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app) with terraform and got this error. The error turned out to be caused by me forgetting to specify the `storage_account_access_key` setting. The docs even mention

> One of storage_account_access_key or storage_uses_managed_identity must be specified when using storage_account_name.

But terraform does not actually check that when applying your configuration, resulting in a cryptic error message much later in the process.